# Automatic update a map in a QGIS layout template to current extent from QGIS canvas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, extents, layouts, template

I'm wondering if there is a way - or a workaround - where a map element in a layout template can be defined to automatically update to current extent when a layout template is used to create a layout.

The case: When I create layout templates I would like to some how define that the extent of a map element in the layout should automatically be updated to the current extent in the map canvas when the layout template is used for a new layout.

I know that the user can click the 'Update to extent' bottom, but it would be nice (a userfriendly) to be able to leave this step out.  Just like when a new map element is added to a layout, it shows the extent of the map canvas.

I have looked into using variables and expressions like *x_min( (@map_extent ))*. When using this expression as a label (in map canvas) it shows the x-min part of the extent, but when it is used in the layout it shows the extent of map-elements in the layout.

Does anyone have a solution or think it would be a good addition to QGIS (then I will create a feature request at QGIS Github page)